# How to use HAC errors in VAR model

Tags: autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, vector-autoregression, statsmodels, robust-standard-error

I would like to use the Newey-West method for the standard errors in a VAR(p)-model (I use [`statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html)). The VAR(p)-model assumes that the residuals are Gaussian white noise. However, I find large BDS test statistics (Broock et al., 1996) for the residuals with several embedded dimensions, meaning that the residuals are not independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.). This motivates the use of Heteroskedasticity and Autocorrelation Corrected (HAC) standard errors. Does anyone know how to implement such an approach in a VAR(p)-model? Or knows another method to correct for the non i.i.d. residuals?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It looks like your question is of the form *How to do something in Python?* (or any other language or software). As such it is off topic. An example of a on topic question is one focusing on understanding the idea behind HAC as applied to VAR and/or working out the formulas for it.

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy. I edited my question to a more general problem and not just a problem specific to Python.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.wouterdenhaan.com/papers/HAND30.pdf. If you still have serial correlation in your residuals after fitting the VAR, that might also simply be an indication to increase the lag order of the VAR